# Gatsby / Drupal 8 - getting an image when using the media module (Acquia Lightning install)

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, gatsby, acquia

On a standard Drupal 8 install using images in a node its fairly easy to get the image via GraphQL. There great examples here:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-drupal

With the Acquia Lightning install profile (or if you're simply using the Media module I expect) Media is adding images differently, in GraphiQL I see the media field in relationships, the only sub field within that is __typename

```
    {
      allNodeBlog {
        edges {
          node {
            relationships {
              field_media {
                __typename
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I can also look at allMediaImage (or similar), in which I do have access to the images themselves. I can also all the node information in the 'relationships', But i need the node data to be the primary information of course. I don't really understand the best way to tie that query together with the nodes.

```
{
  allMediaImage {
    edges {
      node {
        relationships {
          image {
            localFile {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid {
                  ...
                }
              }
            }
          }
          node__blog {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm hoping that I can create the JSON in a different way perhaps to allow easier access to the images. Otherwise a way of getting the node id first then using that to select the appropriate media. Any ideas

Comment: oddly i can images via media if i look at a particular page (this is just one node though and not the general node type i'm after)

{
  nodeBlog {
    relationships {
      node__landing_page {
        relationships {
          field_media {
            relationships {
              image {
                localFile {
                  id
                  childImageSharp {
                    ...
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've worked it out already. But I'm posting a response for anyone else trying to figure this out.

Using Drupal nodes with Gatsby requires you to drill into the relationships between nodes and media entities, *then* into the relationship between the media entities and the files.

I'm using a simple Drupal 8.6.15 install with core Media and (experimental) Media Library enabled. And I have added a media field (image reference) called **Image Asset** (I removed the normal *Image* field) to my *Article* content type.

This is what my graphql query looks like...

```
query ArticleQuery{
  allNodeArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        # Use the node ID for the key in GatsbyJS
        drupal_internal__nid
        # Access the Article's text info
        created(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
        title
        body {
          value
          summary
        }
        # Here is where I access the Image Asset field
        relationships {
          field_image_asset {
            relationships {
              field_media_image {
                localFile {
                  childImageSharp {
                    fluid(maxWidth:1200) {
                      ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```