# GraphQl Query for Node image url without relationships with gatsby-source-drupal

Tags: drupal, gatsby, gatsby-image

- I'm using drupal as a headless CMS for a Gatsby site.
- Each node Type of `Recipe` has an associated image.
- I'm trying to query for each `Recipe` image without having to hop through all it's `relationships`.

**Is there a more direct graphql query for an image than through `relationships` with `gatsby-source-drupal`?**

Gatsby's own [gatsby-source-drupal example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/3f8399b4a9df9f089518c34800cc183c22d68edf/examples/using-drupal/src/templates/recipe.js#L99-L107) uses `relationships` to access a drupal node's images.

```js
query($slug: String!) {
    recipe: nodeRecipe(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      title
      ...
      relationships {
        image: field_image {
          localFile { // NodeType: 'File'
            childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 470, maxHeight: 353) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Context

According to a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032900/gatsby-drupal-8-getting-an-image-when-using-the-media-module-acquia-lightni/55769526#55769526):

> "Using Drupal nodes with Gatsby *requires* you to drill into the relationships between nodes and media entities, then into the relationship between the media entities and the files." [@Spanners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769526/11760796)

I can't help but think there has to be a better way. The query in question yields a node type of 'File', which is a Gatsby built in. But since I need to append fields to the image's node, I'd really rather not do that to the builtin `File` node. It feels like there should be another node Type associated with the images.

***Update***:

- This is what my `localhost:8000/__graphql` looks like

````
  allRecipes { // Query.allRecipes: recipesConnection!
    nodes { // recipesConnection.nodes: [recipes!]!
      id
      relationships { // recipes.relationships: recipesRelationships
        image { // recipesRelationships.image: images
          relationships { // images.relationships: imagesRelationships
            imageFile { // imagesRelationships.imageFile: files
              localFile { // files.localFile: File ...
                url
} ```
````

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `localhost:8000/__graphql` to check what nodes are available when sourcing from Drupal?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Thanks for replying! Yup I did. I tried using the few nodes that come up there but no luck so far. See:     ```query MyQuery {
  allRecipes { // Query.allRecipes: recipesConnection!
    nodes { // recipesConnection.nodes: [recipes!]!
      id
      relationships { // recipes.relationships: recipesRelationships
        image { // recipesRelationships.image: images
          relationships { // images.relationships: imagesRelationships
            imageFile { // imagesRelationships.imageFile: files
              localFile { // files.localFile: File ...
} ```

Comment: Don't you have anything to get all images directly?

Comment: @FerranBuireu ah I see what you mean. So I can do something like `query MyQuery { allImages { nodes { relationships { imageFile { url ..` or `query MyQuery { allFiles(filter: {filename: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}}) { edges { node { url drupal_id ..` to get all the images. But that still leaves me using the `File` node to append my custom field to.